# Magento Admin Category Toggle menu error

Tags: magento, categories, magento-1.6

I have clicked on the category menu in admin but its give me this error on firebugs.

toolbarToggle is not defined toolbarToggle.stop();

Please help me.

NB:My magento updated from 1.4 to 1.6.

Comment: Check this - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/213517/#t287035

Answer (score 2):

It’s a JavaScript bug. Go to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/edit.phtml` comment out line 75 (`toolbarToggle.stop();`) and line 94 (`toolbarToggle.start()`).

Please note, that you will be hacking a core file! You can override these files, but I think it will be fixed in some of the next versions (and then these hacks will be overridden).